# Ionic2-array not updating on html side

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am new in Ionic2 and Angular2 trying to update my array at front side but its not updating.Moreover its updating perfectly at backend (ts),checked using console. need your help

My Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';




   @Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-filter',
  templateUrl: 'modal-filter.html'
})

export class ModalFilterPage {

  public fil=[];
  public BRANDNAME: any;
  public srts:any;



  constructor(public nav: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navParams: NavParams) {
     this.fil = [];
     this.srts="ABCD";
    if (navParams.get('tabName') == 'filter') {
      let data = navParams.get('data');
      data.map(d => {
        for (let op in d.OPTIONGROUP) {
          for (let x in d.OPTIONGROUP[op]) {
            if (x != "UPC") {
              if (!this.fil[x]) {
                this.fil[x] = [];
              }
              if (this.fil[x].indexOf(d.OPTIONGROUP[op][x]) == -1) {

                this.fil[x].push(d.OPTIONGROUP[op][x]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      })


      console.log(this.fil);


    }

  }

  closeModal() {
    // this.nav.pop();
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(true);

  }
}
```

"fil" array not showing on frontside of html but console show its perfectly.

My html code:
**fil array not showing**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Search Result(105)</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding class="tab-filter">
  <!--filter list-->
  <pre>{{fil}}</pre>
  <pre>{{srts}}</pre>
  <ion-list class="list-no-border">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label> PLACE</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option value="">All Regions</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="vn">Vietnam</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="price-ranger">
      <ion-label>Price</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Min"></ion-input>
      -
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Max"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Free shipping</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle checked="false"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Once pice only</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle checked="false"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Sale items</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle checked="false"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>

<!--Footer buttons-->
<ion-footer class="category">
  <ion-toolbar position="bottom">
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        CANCEL
      </button>
      <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
        <span ion-text color="gray">APPLY</span>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: can your try using elvis safe operator with this once like {{fil?}} or like ngIf then fill

Comment: yes I tried ngIf but nothing happened...its length is zero

Comment: Then how can you say it s populating in the backend  can you remove this line from constructor this.fil = [];

Comment: removed but still not working

Comment: What does your `console.log` print?

Comment: try declaring your fil like public fil:any[]; and remove this.fil=[] from constructor. Also use ngIf in your view like this <pre *ngIf="fil">{{fil}}</pre>

Comment: @Ivaro18 console.log result 
[COLOR: Array(33), SIZE: Array(26), PRICE: Array(12), BRAND: Array(1)]

Comment: So I created plunker, I thought maybe the problem had to do something with `data.map` being async (not sure) but after checking, that doesn't affect anything. Can you recreate your issue here? https://plnkr.co/edit/8qa9PdyKWeDWLlskoZqA?p=info

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using

```
this.fil = [];
```

to

```
this.fil={}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `{{fil}}` is an array yet you are declaring it on the view as a simple property. Angular does not automatically interpret an array with string interpolation.

For arrays you need to use `*ngFor`

So if you want like you have stated is being displayed in your `console.log` you could write something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of fil">
     <ion-item *ngFor="let color of item.COLOR">
       {{color.propertyName}}
     <ion-item>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let size of item.SIZE">
       {{color.propertyName}}
     <ion-item>
</div>
```